# Google Maps do not work on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Sorry my bad english.

I have a problem with Google Maps.

I did create a program from the Android Studio by selecting "Google Maps Activity" in the process of creating a new project, the program by connecting a real phone to the computer WORKS, using emulator me It appears written:

> "My Application 90 will not run without Google Play services, Which are missing from your phone."

With under a button that read: "Get Google Play services"

If I click on the button "Get Google Play services" program collapses.
**How do i operate the program even** emulator?

Tell me if I explained well.

Answer (score 14):

You should use emulator with Google API support.

In SDK Manager install system image with Google APIs support (for example, the selected one at screenshot below).

[image: SDK manager]

Then when you create Android virtual device select this system image:

[image: AVD selection]

Answer (score 2):

Create an emulator with Google map Api while you creating Virtual device.  Download google apis from SDK manager.