# android studio - google maps doesn't load

Tags: android, maps

Nothing wrong in my work I have checked everything literally in my android studio nothing needs to be installed all are installed.the api key is right.

I have added all the permissions and still I get a blank screen like this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmBE.png) bellow

[image: screen]

my logcat

Log 1...
[image: screen]

Log2 ...
[image: screen]

UPDATE

and those are the android studio settings with the gradle

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0yMv.png)
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezW8z.png)

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1in1W.png)
[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0qwp.png)

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Probably a problem with the API key

Comment: i had attached my logcat u can view it now @MorrisonChang

Comment: i have opened a tutorial cuz i doubted myself and followed all the steps and still @DanielNugent

Comment: 1. Which tutorial are you following. 2. Which PC/OS are you using 3. Which emulator image/device are you using. The only error I see is the `Google Maps API v2 requires OpenGL ES 2.0` which is odd.

Comment: This might help if you are using an emulator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829057/google-maps-do-not-work-on-emulator

Comment: @MorrisonChang this one  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urLA8z6-l3k .. the tutorial is not really important i guess since the prob happens before i even follow the tut.. plus even after he did run the project it showed him the map and it didn't show up with me 
and i don't really know what does this mean

Comment: @DanielNugent it didn't unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you added your debug/production SHA-1 key to Google API console?

2) `Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above` suggests your device is not supported.

Comment: yes ! .. once i just click new google map activity i copy the link that's given then i create the api key and it automaticaly copy my SHA-1 key with the package name there ,, so all i have to do is to copy the key that  it gave me to my .xml where it says "KEY_HERE " ..

also i have updated all the tools and play services plus updating the emulator itself .. and i added all the permissions and the play-services too ! nothing wong i'm sure ! .. yes please explain what should i do after it not being supported ?

Comment: I have added more pics of my gradle and my settings u can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Hi there might be 2 scenerio

1) If you are running on a real device then you missed  to add feature required for OpenGL ES 2.0.

In this case just add the following code in your project's AndroidManifest.xml file before application tag:

```html
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

2) If you are running on emulator then you need to use

**Emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.**

Comment: unfortunatly it didn't work .. it doesn't install on my real device and doesn't show map on my AVD .. i have added more pics of my android settings options and my gradle .. u can take a look please if u would like to

Comment: Try to add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in your project gradle and you are using build tool of 26 so use implementation instead of compile